# doing basic bitmap color changes to a plot window?

Tags: r

Suppose I've created a plot like this:

```
plot(1:100, 201:300, col="red")
points(1:100, 221:320, col="green")
```

Is there any way to make basic bitmap-style color changes on the plot? Like desaturate the plot to make it monochrome (black and white), or to change green pixels into blue pixels?

I am looking for a general-purpose approach that can be applied to any plot window. For example, if the plot window were to contain a colorful map, I may want to change it to B&W.

Comment: AFAIK this sort of thing is not really handled by R plotting packages after you've created a plot. You might want to investigate something like exporting to `?svg` and applying filters and edits in an external package like Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously a lot of good reasons not to do it in R, but you can use `png` library to manipulate a plot that's been sent to the `grDevices::png` device:

```
png("test.png",600,400)
plot(1:100, 201:300, col="red")
points(1:100, 221:320, col="green")
dev.off()

require(png) # png library
p.0<-readPNG("test.png") # load image
```

[image]

```
# color switch
p.colshift<-p.0               # make a copy

p.colshift[,,2]<-p.0[,,3]     # make G <- old B
p.colshift[,,3]<-p.0[,,2]     # make B <- old G

writePNG(p.colshift,"test-colshift.png")
```

[image]

```
# desaturate
p.desat<-p.0               # make a copy

desatmap<-(p.0[,,1]+p.0[,,2]+p.0[,,3])/3  # get average of R,G,B (not alpha : ,,4)
lapply(1:3,function(x)p.desat[,,x]<<-desatmap) # set each of R,G,B to the "average" - equal results == greyscale
writePNG(p.desat,"test-desat.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Once I convert it to PNG, the coordinate system is gone, right? Ideally, I'd like to convert to black and white **and** still keep the coordinate system so I can keep plotting. For example, with maps, I'd like to convert a colorful base map to B&W and then plot color lines on top.

Comment: Actually I don't think there's an easy way in base `plot` to do it by color, as the plot is objects not pixels. Probably the quickest way would be to overplot the points: `points(1:100, 221:320, col="blue")` to replace green with blue. In `ggplot2` you could use `ggplot_build()` to "look inside" the object and dynamically replace/adjust colors.